# How to show the right fieldset when I click a step from a multistep form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I've been struggling with this problem 2 entire days. Any help would be appreciated!

I have a multistep form (splitted by fieldsets) with a progress bar and when I click NEXT it shows the next fieldset and PREVIOUS takes me back to the previous fieldset.

I have the progress bar above and I would like to click step 2 and show me the second fieldset. Or if I click step 3, show me the third fieldset. Can someone help me please?

Here is the CodePen code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Pyqxvy

Thanks in advance for help.

Also, here is the code:

```js
//jQuery time
(function($) {
  var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
  var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
  var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

  $(".next").click(function() {
    if (animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

    //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

    //show the next fieldset
    next_fs.show();
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, {
      step: function(now, mx) {
        //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
        //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
        scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
        //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
        left = (now * 50) + "%";
        //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
        opacity = 1 - now;
        current_fs.css({
          'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')'
        });
        next_fs.css({
          'left': left,
          'opacity': opacity
        });
      },
      duration: 800,
      complete: function() {
        current_fs.hide();
        animating = false;
      },
      //this comes from the custom easing plugin
      easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
  });

  $(".previous").click(function() {
    if (animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

    //de-activate current step on progressbar
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

    //show the previous fieldset
    previous_fs.show();
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, {
      step: function(now, mx) {
        //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
        //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
        scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
        //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
        left = ((1 - now) * 50) + "%";
        //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
        opacity = 1 - now;
        current_fs.css({
          'left': left
        });
        previous_fs.css({
          'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
          'opacity': opacity
        });
      },
      duration: 800,
      complete: function() {
        current_fs.hide();
        animating = false;
      },
      //this comes from the custom easing plugin
      easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
  });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/* css class for the registration form generated errors */

.profilepress-reg-status {
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 1.471;
  padding: 10px 19px;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 5px 0;
}


/*form styles*/

#msform {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto 550px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

#msform fieldset {
  background: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding: 20px 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 10%;
  /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
  position: absolute;
}


/*Hide all except first fieldset*/

#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}


/*inputs*/

#msform input,
#msform textarea {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: montserrat;
  color: #2C3E50;
  font-size: 13px;
}


/*buttons*/

#msform .action-button {
  width: 100px;
  background: #27AE60;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
}

#msform .action-button:hover,
#msform .action-button:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}


/*headings*/

.fs-title {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #2C3E50;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.fs-subtitle {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #666;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}


/*progressbar*/

#progressbar {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
  counter-reset: step;
}

#progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #616161;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 9px;
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

#progressbar li:before {
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #333;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}

#progressbar li:first-child:after {
  /*connector not needed before the first step*/
  content: none;
}


/*marking active/completed steps green*/


/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/

#progressbar li.active:before,
#progressbar li.active:after {
  background: #27AE60;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" novalidate>
  <div id="msform">
    <!-- progressbar -->
    <ul id="progressbar">
      <li class="active">Account Setup</li>
      <li>Social Profiles</li>
      <li>Personal Details</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- fieldsets -->
    <fieldset>
      <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
      <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
      <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
      <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
      <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <h2 class="fs-title">Social Profiles</h2>
      <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your presence on the social network</h3>
      <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter" />
      <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" />
      <input type="text" name="gplus" placeholder="Google Plus" />
      <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
      <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Detail</h2>
      <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
      <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
      <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
      <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
      <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
      <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added an event listener for `click` on `#progressbar li`. I have modified your `next()` and `prev()`.

```js
//jQuery time
(function($) {
  var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
  var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
  var animating = false; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches
  
  // EDITED
  
  $('#progressbar li').click(function() {
    var active_index = $('li.active').index(); // getting the active li
    var goto_index = $(this).index(); // getting the li on which user clicked
    
    var active_form = $('fieldset').eq(active_index);
    var goto_form = $('fieldset').eq(goto_index);
    var i = 1; // factor of time interval
    var cpy_index = active_index;
        
    if(goto_index > active_index) {
      while(goto_index > active_index) {
        active_index++;
        
        setTimeout(() => {
          nextElem(active_form.find('.action-button')); // animate to next form
          cpy_index++;
          active_form = $('fieldset').eq(cpy_index); // getting next form (if required)
        }, i * 1000);
        
        i++;
      }
    } else if(goto_index < active_index) {
      while(goto_index < active_index) {
        active_index--;
        
        setTimeout(() => {
          previous(active_form.find('.action-button')); // animate to previous form
          cpy_index--;
          active_form = $('fieldset').eq(cpy_index); // getting previous form
        }, i * 1000);
        
        i++;
      }
    }
  });
  
  // EDITED
  
  $(".next").click(function() { nextElem(this); });
  
  // Made a separate function for multiple use
  function nextElem(elem) {
    if (animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(elem).parent();
    next_fs = $(elem).parent().next();

    //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

    //show the next fieldset
    next_fs.show();
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, {
      step: function(now, mx) {
        //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
        //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
        scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
        //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
        left = (now * 50) + "%";
        //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
        opacity = 1 - now;
        current_fs.css({
          'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')'
        });
        next_fs.css({
          'left': left,
          'opacity': opacity
        });
      },
      duration: 800,
      complete: function() {
        current_fs.hide();
        animating = false;
      },
      //this comes from the custom easing plugin
      easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
  }

  $(".previous").click(function() { previous(this); });
  
  // Made a separate function for multiple use
  function previous(elem) {
    if (animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(elem).parent();
    previous_fs = $(elem).parent().prev();

    //de-activate current step on progressbar
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(previous_fs)).addClass("active");
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

    //show the previous fieldset
    previous_fs.show();
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, {
      step: function(now, mx) {
        //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
        //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
        scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
        //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
        left = ((1 - now) * 50) + "%";
        //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
        opacity = 1 - now;
        current_fs.css({
          'left': left
        });
        previous_fs.css({
          'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
          'opacity': opacity
        });
      },
      duration: 800,
      complete: function() {
        current_fs.hide();
        animating = false;
      },
      //this comes from the custom easing plugin
      easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
  }

})(jQuery);
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/* css class for the registration form generated errors */

.profilepress-reg-status {
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 1.471;
  padding: 10px 19px;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 5px 0;
}


/*form styles*/

#msform {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto 550px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

#msform fieldset {
  background: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding: 20px 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 10%;
  /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
  position: absolute;
}


/*Hide all except first fieldset*/

#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}


/*inputs*/

#msform input,
#msform textarea {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: montserrat;
  color: #2C3E50;
  font-size: 13px;
}


/*buttons*/

#msform .action-button {
  width: 100px;
  background: #27AE60;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
}

#msform .action-button:hover,
#msform .action-button:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}


/*headings*/

.fs-title {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #2C3E50;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.fs-subtitle {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #666;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}


/*progressbar*/

#progressbar {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
  counter-reset: step;
}

#progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #616161;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 9px;
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

#progressbar li:before {
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #333;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}

#progressbar li:first-child:after {
  /*connector not needed before the first step*/
  content: none;
}


/*marking active/completed steps green*/


/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/

#progressbar li.active:before,
#progressbar li.active:after {
  background: #27AE60;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" novalidate>
  <div id="msform">
    <!-- progressbar -->
    <ul id="progressbar">
      <li class="active">Account Setup</li>
      <li>Social Profiles</li>
      <li>Personal Details</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- fieldsets -->
    <fieldset>
      <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
      <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
      <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
      <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
      <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <h2 class="fs-title">Social Profiles</h2>
      <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your presence on the social network</h3>
      <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter" />
      <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" />
      <input type="text" name="gplus" placeholder="Google Plus" />
      <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
      <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Detail</h2>
      <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
      <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
      <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
      <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
      <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
      <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh, you saved my day. Thanks a lot!! Do you have any idea how can I make it to go directly to that step (instead of going to every step until the one I want to reach)?

Comment: For the direct jump, you'll have to add a second parameter in your `next()` and `prev()` function. And, the second parameter would be the `next_fs` or `prev_fs` depending on the jump.